# Get item created date in Sitecore

Tags: c#, .net, content-management-system, sitecore

Is there anyway we can get an item's created date programmatically under the Statistics section?
Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes.  `Sitecore.Context.Item.Statistics.Created`.  This returns the item's created date as a `DateTime` object.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend messing with this value and just let Sitecore set it but you could via: `Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["__Created"].Value`.  You would just have to set the value in the proper string format `yyyyMMddThhmmss` (I think).

Comment: I came across this answer while searching for an item's updated date. For reference, you can access the updated date using the Sitecore.Context.Item.Statistics.Update field. It returns a DateTime object just like the Created field does.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get the creation date of a media item and the only way it worked was this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(item.InnerItem.Fields["__Created"].Value.Substring(0,8), "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's one important detail that wasn't mentioned yet:

- `item.Created` (returns the DateTime that the item was first created)
- `item.Statistics.Created` (returns the DateTime that the latest *version* was created)